# How to check if object has property javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
      function ddd(object) {
        if (object.id !== null) {
            //do something...
        } 
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

How can I check if object has property and to check the property value??

Comment: You can use `if(object.property)` or `if(object.hasOwnProperty('property'))`

Comment: Try `if (typeof(object.id) !== 'undefined')`

Comment: use `obj.hasOwnProperty("id")`

Comment: Your error doesn't have anything to do with `id` - your `object` itself is null. `if (object && object.id !== null)` would solve that.

Comment: By the way, I would avoid naming a variable `object` - it seems like it's ok in javascript, but other languages have `object` as a keyword, and `Object` is reserved, so I'd personally stick with `obj` or another alternative, if you don't have a more meaningful name.

Comment: I actually don't think this is a duplicate.  you asked "and to check the property value?"

to check the value, try "[optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)"


`if (obj?.id !== null) {...}`

Answer (score 25):

`hasOwnProperty` is the method you're looking for

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

As an alternative, you can do something like:

```
if (typeof object.id !== 'undefined') {
    // note that the variable is defined, but could still be 'null'
}
```

In this particular case, the error you're seeing suggests that `object` is null, not `id` so be wary of that scenario.

For testing awkward deeply nested properties of various things like this, I use [brototype](https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype).

Comment: My linter says this is deprecated. Is there another way to handle this? Using React.

Comment: it is faster to just do `if (object.id) { // do stuff }` but this has issues if `object.id` is `false` or `0`